# how to make available promise data object in controller and pass data from promise to new function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written angular controller and service to read data from json file. service read data and passes it to controller it works fine but when I try to assign this data to new object it wont work.

I want to call a new function in my promise and pass my data as object to this new function so I can use it whereever required.
controller code,

```
class WPEntryController {
    static $inject = ["$location", "WPEntryService"];
    constructor($location, WPEntryService, $http) {
        console.log("IN WPEntryController");
        this.$location = $location;
        this.WPEntryService = WPEntryService;
        this.loadWPEntryPagewithData();

    }
    loadWPEntryPagewithData(){
        this.WPEntryService.loadWPEntryData().then(function(promise){
           this.DataObject = promise;
            this.storeObject();
        });
    }
    storeObject() {
        console.log(this.DataObject);
    }
}
angular.module("app").controller("WPEntryController", WPEntryController);
```

services code,

```
class WPEntryService {
  static $inject = ["$http"];
  constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
  }
    loadWPEntryData() {
        //read json file or provide URL for data
        var promise = this.$http.get('...')
            .then(function (dataObject) {
                return dataObject.data;
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        return promise;
    }
}

angular.module('app').service('WPEntryService',WPEntryService);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want `catch(function (response) {
                return response;
            });`? That ignores errors and fulfills the promise with them.

Answer (score 0):

You're having the [wrong `this` context in your `then` callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572). Use an arrow function instead:

```
loadWPEntryPagewithData(){
    this.WPEntryService.loadWPEntryData().then(dataObject => {
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        this.DataObject = dataObject;
        this.storeObject();
    });
}
```

However, this approach is still fragile and might not work as expected. It's much better to store the promise itself in that instance slot:

```
loadWPEntryPagewithData(){
    this.DataPromise = this.WPEntryService.loadWPEntryData();
    this.storeObject();
}
storeObject() {
    this.DataPromise.then(DataObject => console.log(DataObject));
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code worked, but still I am not able to pass this DataObject to another function

Comment: What other function? And when are you trying to pass it around, are you sure it has loaded already? That's why I recommend to store `DataPromise`.

Comment: What I mean is, if I try to assign this.menu = DataObject in my storeObject() I get undefined error.

Comment: Well there is no variable `DataObject` in the function scope (unless you're in the promise `then` callback). Maybe you should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and post your current code.